# Exam Proof Read: $\forall x,~\exists y\ni\forall z,~[(z>y)\implies (z>x+y)]$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inequality

I just got my exam back, and the question went like this:

> Determine the truth value of the following statement, assuming that $x$, $y$, and $z$ are real numbers. Justify your answer.
>   $$\forall x,~\exists y\ni\forall z,~[(z>y)\implies (z>x+y)]$$

So I said, "True. Let $y=(z-x+1)$." I meant "False." I got $\varnothing$ points. `:-(`

Comment: Oh, and my question is does this seem just?

Comment: What is $\ni$ sign for?

Comment: It means "such that."

Comment: @Trancot Your counter example is wrong. You can't specify $y$ in terms of $z$ because the **existencial** quantifier which bounds $y$ **precedes** the **universal** quantifier which bounds $z$.Also I think in such questions writing down the right answer with a false justification is usually worth $\varnothing$ points. (And $\varnothing$ is so right).

Comment: Are you sure $x=-1$ is a counter example? I'm probably just confused but I thought the statement was false for positive $x$. (and correct for $x<= 0$)

Comment: I am also not so good on directions.

Answer (score 2):

Your counter example is wrong. You can't specify $y$ in terms of $z$ because the **existential** quantifier which bounds $y$ **precedes** the **universal** quantifier which bounds $z$. The bold words are there for you to note that you can't even argue that you could swap the order of the quantifiers.

Since the statement is of the form $\color{green}\forall \exists\forall \text{ condition}$, a counter-example to show it is false is merely an example of a real number that replaces the variable of the green universal quantifier. You then need to prove that the **existential** statement that arises can't be true.

I suggest the counter example $x=1$. If there was an $y$ that made the statement true, it would also be true for $z=y+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the **negation** of the original statement.

$$ \exists x : \forall y, \exists z : \neg [ (z > y) \implies (z > x+y)],$$

or equivalently,

$$ \exists x : \forall y, \exists z :  [ (z > y) \wedge (z \leq x+y)].$$

Better still, using some algebra, $(z > y) \Leftrightarrow (z+x > x+y)$, the inequalities can be combined:

$$ \exists x : \forall y, \exists z :  [ z \leq x+y < x+z ]. $$

Then by choosing $x=1$, and for any $y$, choose $z = y + 1$, the previous statement is true.  Thus, the original is **false** (with the same choices 
for $x, y, z$ now providing a *counter-example*).

Hope this helps!